# Swift mutable set: Duplicate element found

Tags: swift, set, mutable

My app uses mutable sets of custom elements. Once I had a crash with error „Duplicate element found in Set. Elements may have been mutated after insertion.“

Searching for an explanation, I found [this post](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-set-crash-duplicate-element-found-in-set-elements-may-have-been-mutated-after-insertion/16992), which I don’t fully understand.
My impression is that one should not modify an element of a set, since this would modify also the hash value of the set, so that further accesses might fail.

My questions:

- Is it allowed to modify an element of a mutable set, or which modifications are allowed, if any?
- If not, do I have first to remove the element from the set, then modify it, and then insert it back?

EDIT:

To phrase it differently: Is it safe to modify the property of a custom element of a mutable set, without modifying the set itself?

Comment: Are your custom object class is confirming to Hasable protocol ? if so then can you show us code where it is crashing

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set), Swift sets MUST conform to the Hashable protocol, so my custom elements do. Actually, I eliminated the crash by a workaround some time ago, and left a TODO to clarify the situation. So I cannot show the crashing code.

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted?

Comment: ok got it.... duplicate will come only if your custom object won't conform to Hashable protocol.

Comment: Are you saying that one can insert an object that does not conform to the Hashing protocol anyway in a Swift set, without a compiler warning?

Comment: yeah you can do it and in this case it will work.

Comment: I do not have a reference, but I am sure that after insertion into a set, you must *not* modify the instance in any way that the hash value or testing for equality is affected.

Comment: @Martin R: I (and somebody else) think you are right. Maybe you should make your comment to an answer so that I can close the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The implementation of Swift sets is similar to that of dictionaries, which is described nicely in [Exploring Swift Dictionary's Implementation](http://ankit.im/swift/2016/01/19/exploring-swift-dictionary-implementation/). In particular, the element storage is a list of “buckets“ each of which can be occupied or not. When a new element is inserted into the set, its hash value is used to determine the initial bucket. If that bucket is occupied, a linear search for the next free bucket is done. Similarly, when searching an element in the set, the hash value is used for determining the initial bucket, and then a linear search is done until the element (or an unoccupied bucket) is found.

(The details can be found in the open source implementation, the most relevant source files are 
[Set.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Set.swift), [NativeSet.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/NativeSet.swift), [SetStorage.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/SetStorage.swift) and [HashTable.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/HashTable.swift).)

Mutating the hash value of an inserted element breaks the invariants of the set storage implementation: Locating an element via its initial bucket no longer works. And mutating other properties which affect equality can lead to multiple “equal” elements in the same bucket list.

Therefore I think it is safe to say that

> After inserting an instance of a reference type into a set, the properties of that instance must not be modified in a way that affects its hash value or testing for equality.

**Examples**

First, this is only a problem for sets of a *reference type.* A set of a value type contains independent copies of the value, and modifying a property of that value after the insertion does not affect the set:

```
struct Foo: Hashable {
    var x: Int
}

var set = Set<Foo>()
var foo = Foo(x: 1)
set.insert(foo)
print(set.map { $0.x })   // [1]
foo.x = 2
print(set.map { $0.x })   // [1]
set.insert(foo)
print(set.map { $0.x })   // [1, 2]
```

Instances of a reference type are “pointers” to the actual object storage, and modifying  a property of that instance does not mutate the reference. It is therefore possible to modify a property of an instance after it has been inserted into a set:

```
class Bar: Hashable {
    var x : Int

    init(x: Int) { self.x = x }

    static func == (lhs: Bar, rhs: Bar) -> Bool { return lhs.x == rhs.x }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) { hasher.combine(x) }
}

var set = Set<Bar>()
let bar = Bar(x: 1)
set.insert(bar)
print(set.map { $0.x })   // [1]
bar.x = 2
print(set.map { $0.x })   // [2]
```

However, this leads to crashes easily, e.g. if we insert the same reference again:

```
set.insert(bar)
```

```
Fatal error: Duplicate elements of type 'Bar' were found in a Set.
This usually means either that the type violates Hashable's requirements, or
that members of such a set were mutated after insertion.
```

Here is another example, where the hash value is identical for all instances, but modifying a property which is used for equality testing leads to a set of two “equal” instances:

```
class Baz: Hashable {
    var x : Int

    init(x: Int) { self.x = x }

    static func == (lhs: Baz, rhs: Baz) -> Bool { return lhs.x == rhs.x }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) { }
}

var set = Set<Baz>()
let baz1 = Baz(x: 1)
set.insert(baz1)
let baz2 = Baz(x: 2)
set.insert(baz2)
baz1.x = 2

print(set.map { $0.x })   // [2, 2]
print(set.count)             // 2
print(Set(Array(set)).count) // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Allowed Operations:** You can add, remove, update elements from `NSMutableSet`. If you want to update/add an element then you have to call `.add()` method, it will add a given object to the set, if it is not already a member.

Please check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableset) Apple documentation regarding NSMutableSet.

You can perform all types of operations like add,remove,update etc.

Comment: Sorry, that I did not phase my question clear enough: I wanted to know, if I can modify a property of an element of the set without changing the set itself.

Answer (score -5):

Basically swift stdlib is a (quite often) unuseable kind of trash (similar to C++ STL and other c++ trash tech). The things that work out of the box in NextStep legacy take
days (if ever) to get it right in swift runtime (such as Set).

I spent around two working days chasing the <s>faux</s> hash and == mismatch
ditched swift Set in favor of NSMutableSet and somehow my app is very fine now.

Did I mention swift runtime is trash?

This:

```
public extension NSSet
{
    var isEmpty: Bool {
        return count == 0
    }
}
public extension NSMutableSet
{
    func insert(_ item: Any)
    {
        add(item)
    }
}
```

will help you to convert seamlessly