# Combining hash of Date and String

Tags: swift, hash

I have a NSObject consisting of a bunch of properties.
The NSObject can uniquely be identified using a Date property and a String property. What is the best way to create a hash using these two variables?

I could do something like  `date.hashValue ^ string.hashValue`, but it seems the hashes differ for each object.

The object looks like this:

```
class Something : Model {
    public var name: String!
    public var time: Date!

    override var hash : Int {
       return time.hashValue ^ name.hashValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but you are strongly discouraged from declaring properties IUO as a workaround not to write an initializer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will refactor in that improvement as soon as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `NSObject` subclasses you must override the `hash` property and the `isEqual:` method, compare [NSObject subclass in Swift: hash vs hashValue, isEqual vs ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319959/nsobject-subclass-in-swift-hash-vs-hashvalue-isequal-vs).

For the implementation of the `hash` property you can use the `Hasher` class introduced in Swift 4.2, and its [`combine()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hasher/2995578-combine) method:

> Adds the given value to this hasher, mixing its essential parts into the hasher state.

I would also suggest to make the properties *constant,* since mutating them after an object is inserted into a hashable collection (set, dictionary) causes undefined behaviour, compare [Swift mutable set: Duplicate element found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55674205/swift-mutable-set-duplicate-element-found).

```
class Model: NSObject { /* ... */ }


class Something : Model {
    let name: String
    let time: Date

    init(name: String, time: Date) {
        self.name = name
        self.time = time
    }

    override var hash : Int {
        var hasher = Hasher()
        hasher.combine(name)
        hasher.combine(time)
        return hasher.finalize()
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Something, rhs: Something) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.time == rhs.time
    }
}
```