# are dictionary keys that conform to Hashable protocol having update to its reference object

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

Say I had a class called `Example`, it conforms to `Hashable` via its `ID` attribute.

I have an Example object `exam1`, with `ID = 6` and `name = "goon"`.  I set a dictionary entry `dict[exam1] = 7`.

Then lets say I had another example object with the same `ID`, but different data inside. Let's call it `exam2`, with `ID = 6`, `name = "pie"`.

If I set `dict[exam2] = 8`, this would index to the same entry as before because their IDs are the same. However, **would the key be updated to reference exam2?** so `dict.keys` would contain reference to `exam2`, not `exam1`.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Using reference types (classes) as dictionary keys *and* mutating their properties after insertion into a dictionary (or set) is a bad idea, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/55674205/1187415.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Django Model object to dict with all of the fields intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925671/convert-django-model-object-to-dict-with-all-of-the-fields-intact)

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary will contain instance of `exam1`, not `exam2`. Reason: as the [documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary)

> Update an existing value by assigning a new value to a key that already exists in the dictionary.

In other words, the assignment `dict[x] = y` can modify the value, but will never modify the key, it can only add it (if the key is not yet in dictionary) or remove it (if the value is nil).

But as someone mentioned above, this is a really bad idea. The meaning of `Hashable` is

> Hashing a value means feeding its essential components into a hash function, represented by the Hasher type. Essential components are those that contribute to the type’s implementation of Equatable. Two instances that are equal must feed the same values to Hasher in hash(into:), in the same order.

And that takes us to the meaning of Equatable (which you will also have to implement as a part of conforming to Hashable:

> Equality implies substitutability—any two instances that compare equally can be used interchangeably in any code that depends on their values.

So when you defined your Hashable, as "ID only", you state that `name` is not an essential component and that `exam1 == exam2` (even though their `name` property has different values). This is *legal* from the language perspective, but a huge potential to bugs and issues in the future.